# Using multibib without an extra title

Tags: multibib

When using

```
\newcites{novels}{Novels}
```

in the package multibib, then I can cite with

```
\citenovels{entry}.
```

And I get an extra bibliography with title Novels.

Unfortunately, I do not want to have a title for this extra bibliography, but using

```
\newcites{novels}{}
```

gives me an error. What can I do to get rid of the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends on the document class.

**article** Add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\removebibheader
  {\xpatchcmd\std@thebibliography
    {\section*{\refname}%
     \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
    }{}{}{}%
  }
\makeatother
```

**scrartcl, scrreprt, scrbook** Add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\removebibheader{\let\bib@heading\relax}
\makeatother
```

**Moreover, for all of the above classes:** Define the new bibliography with whatever title you like, e.g.

```
\newcites{novels}{Novels}
```

At the place where you include the bibliography, execute the command `\removebibheader` before. In order not to affect other bibliographies, surround it and the `\bibliograhy...` command by braces.

```
{\removebibheader
 \bibliographynovels{novels}
}
```

Here is an example with full code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{novels}{Novels}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\removebibheader
  {\xpatchcmd\std@thebibliography
    {\section*{\refname}%
     \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
    }{}{}{}%
  }
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\citenovels{entry}
\blindtext
\bibliographystylenovels{plain}
{\removebibheader
 \bibliographynovels{novels}
}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, for the `scrartcl` class:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{novels}{Novels}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\removebibheader{\let\bib@heading\relax}
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\citenovels{entry}
\blindtext
\bibliographystylenovels{plain}
{\removebibheader
 \bibliographynovels{novels}
}
\end{document}
```

Contents of `novels.bib`:

```
@article{entry,
author = {The author},
title = {The novel},
journal = {The journal},
year=2016
}
```

Comment: it works but unfortunately there is a really big space then before the bibliography starts

Comment: I've modified my answer.

Comment: I followed your instructions: It does not work, the heading is still there.

Comment: The only difference to your example is that I use \bibliographystylenovels{abbrv} and have a \section{Novels} before \bibliographystylenovels{abbrv}. Moreover, I use scrartcl.

Comment: since in your command there appers \section it maybe has something to do with the fact that I use \section{Novels} before..

Comment: @John_Doe Different document classes handle section headings (like the one for the bibliography) differently. I have updated my answer for the `scrartcl` class.

Answer (score 0):

With the report or book classes, you can use:

```
\begingroup
   \def\chapter*#1{}
   \bibliography ...
\endgroup
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for three days, I found a very simple solution to remove the title regardless of the file class or any other package being used simultaneously: rather than leaving the title argument empty, you need to use the {} as the argument for each new citation:

in short: \newcites{main,method}{{},{}}

```
\documentclass{extarticle} 
%any other class should work, i have tried IEEEtran and article and it did work just %fine
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{main,method}{{},{}} 

% here rather than leaving the argument as empty use  empty curly brackets

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\citemain{entry1}
%assuming there exist references with the key named "entry1" and "entry2"  in the bib file
\bibliographystylemain{plain}
\bibliographymain{refs} 
 %assuming there is a bib file with the name "refs"
\blindtext
\citemethod{entry2}
\bibliographystylemethod{plain}
\bibliographymethod{refs}  
\end{document}
```

assuming the name of the .tex file is "document", run

pdflatex document

bibtex main.aux

bibtex method.aux

pdflatex document

pdflatex document

Answer (score 0):

If your documentclass is `moderncv`, you can do `\renewcommand*{\bibliographyhead}[1]{}` before `\bibliography`. Surround both with an enclosing `{}` if the title should be removed for only one of the bibliographies:

```
{\renewcommand*{\bibliographyhead}[1]{}
 \bibliographynovels{novels}
}
```