# Using multibib without an extra title in amsart

Tags: amsart, multibib

I have almost exactly the same question as asked in [Using multibib without an extra title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344079/using-multibib-without-an-extra-title), however, with a different documentclass: amsart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same approach as gernot in his answer, you can define `\removebibheader` as:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removebibheader}{%
  \let\@bibtitlestyle\relax
}
\makeatother
```

You would then place the command before the bibliography, surrounding it by block quotes:

```
{\removebibheader
 \bibliographynovels{novels}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the job. However, if the respective reference list is preceded by a subsection (with no text in between), it also shrinks the heading of the subsection to smallfont.

Comment: The heading is set to the `\bibliofont`, which is defined in amsart as `\footnotesize`, because by nullifying the `\@bibtitlestyle` we also nullified the code in `\@startsection` that started a new paragraph. You can fix this by adding this line of code to the definition of `\removebibheader`: `\if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi\par`